# Manjaro lsb-release set to Arch (lsb-release: /etc/lsb-release exists in filesystem)

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, pacman, lsb-release

I tried upgrading my packages with `pacman -Syu` and got an error message.

```
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
lsb-release: /etc/lsb-release exists in filesystem (owned by manjaro-release)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

So I thought I could try backing up the `/etc/lsb-release` file (with another name) so maybe the conflict would be resolved after doing another upgrade.

Although running `pacman -Syu` again now succeeds without errors, the `/etc/lsb-release` file contains the following:

```
LSB_VERSION=1.4
DISTRIB_ID=Arch
DISTRIB_RELEASE=rolling
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Arch Linux"
```

While it used to contain:

```
DISTRIB_ID=ManjaroLinux
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.1.6
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Pahvo
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Manjaro Linux"
```

So my system is now recognizing Arch as its distribution which is not right. Is it possible to reverse this action and what did I do wrong?

Comment: Which package does own `/etc/lsb-release` right now? (I.e. what is the output of `pacman -Qo /etc/lsb-release`? Did you add any Arch repository to your `pacman` configuration or tried installing packages from Arch repositories recently?

Comment: @fra-san the issue was I added arch mirrors to pacmans mirrorlist. Someone online had done exact the same thing so I was able to resolve my issue following [this link](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/added-arch-linux-mirrors-to-pacman-mirrorlist-file-by-mistake-fixed-it-but-will-there-be-any-issues-after-restart/128409)